# Hyperlink String that will be sent in sms

Tags: android, string, hyperlink

I am trying to hyperlink a word in a string, but I cannot figure out why its not working. I have taken examples from stack overflow on how to do it, but still not working. 
I am trying to send an sms with text using a string resource. when the person receives the text they will be able to click on the hyperlink to download the app.
the text sends no problem but the text does not hyperlink
Here is my code (I have omitted some of the text):

`
    App

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="appwidget_text">App</string>
<string name="add_widget">Add widget</string>

<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
<string name="download">Download
            <a href='https://play.google.com/apps/>App</a>
</string>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

SMS does not support HTML.

Whether something "hyperlinks" or not depends on each phone's capability (on the receiver site) and anything not containing `http://` is guaranteed not to be clickable.

You might have success with `bit.ly` and other URL shorteners to fit in an acceptable length.

Comment: I tried using '<a href='http://tinyurl.com/qyo3ogb'> App</a>' but it didnt work. Hmm not sure what else to try